# any example of non-zero ordinals $a,b,c$ for which $a < b$, but $a^c \ge b^c$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am working from a book that gives the above problem, but no solution ;^(.

That is:

> Show an example of non-zero ordinals $a,b,c$ for which $a < b$,  but  $a^c 
> \ge b^c$.

Exponentiation here is ordinal exponentiation.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide !

Comment: A big hint: under ordinal exponentiation, what is $2^\omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Take $c=\omega$. $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: Thanks, Professor Scott & Steven.  I reviewed the definition of ordinal exponentiation and the answers given make perfect sense now.

Comment: @Chris: Glad to hear it; you’re welcome.

Comment: @ChrisBedford Note that it's not really dependent on ordinal exponentiation, eiither; the same choices work for cardinal exponentiation. The real lesson here is that $\lt$ isn't continuous through limits, which you already know in a different disguise: $1\lt\frac{n+1}{n}$ for all $n$, but $1\not\lt\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}$.

Comment: vaguely remember this, as my calculus was 30 years back  ;^)    But  now that  you mention it, it sure does  makes sense !  thanks again.